# Fetch URLs from a Text File Using Python

Tags: python

I have a list of URLs in a text file that I would like to fetch using `urllib2`. I know you can use `urllib2.urlopen(the_url)` to read the content from the url, but how can I make it so Python reads those URLs line by line as they are in the text file and prints the results?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read [Reading and Writing Files](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in the tutorial? If so, what part are you confused about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file just consists of one URL per line, you can just do:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        url = urllib2.urlopen(line)
        ...
```

Is there something about the way the file is formatted that makes this more complicated?

Comment: You probably want `line.rstrip()` there.

Comment: Hi qwrrty, this method prints the URLs fine from the file, but I don't get the results from those URLs. For example, if I have the API URL like https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=1, it should print a result.

Comment: @abarnert urllib2.urlopen() seems to work implicitly with trailing newlines on the URLs I tested. (But perhaps that's a quirk of the servers that I tested against.)

Comment: @kolor Once you have opened the URL with `urllib2.urlopen()` then you may read from it and do whatever you like with the data.

Comment: @qwrrty That's what I'm trying to do. If I use `urllib2.urlopen(line)`, then Python just prints the URL from the file. However, if I do `urllib2.urlopen(insert_url_directly)`, then Python prints the result from that URL. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Seems straight-forward. I'm not an experienced user of Python.

Comment: @qwrrty: I think it's a quirk of `urllib2`, actually… but it's not documented, so I'd rather not count on it.